# Does MailboxProcessor just duplicate IObservable?

Tags: f#, system.reactive, actor

I want to process to types of a message

`Add x` makes program remember number x

`Print` makes it print all remembered numbers

Why would I write this:

```
open System
type Message =
    | Add of int
    | Print
let mailbox = new MailboxProcessor<Message>(fun inbox -> 
        let rec loop history = async{
            let! msg=inbox.Receive()
            match msg with
                | Add x -> return! loop(history + x.ToString()+" ")
                | Print ->
                    printfn "%s" history
                    return! loop(history)
        }
        loop ""
    )
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    mailbox.Start()
    mailbox.Post(Add 12)
    mailbox.Post(Add 56)
    mailbox.Post(Print)
    mailbox.Post(Add 34)
    mailbox.Post(Print)
    ignore <| Console.ReadLine()
    0
```

instead of this:

```
open System
open System.Reactive.Subjects
type Message =
    | Add of int
    | Print
let subject = new Subject<Message>() 
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    subject
        |> Observable.scan(fun history msg -> 
                match msg with
                        | Add x -> history + x.ToString()+" "
                        | Print ->
                            printfn "%s" history
                            history
            ) ""
        |> Observable.subscribe(fun _->())
        |> ignore
    subject.OnNext(Add 12)
    subject.OnNext(Add 56)
    subject.OnNext(Print)
    subject.OnNext(Add 34)
    subject.OnNext(Print)
    ignore <| Console.ReadLine()
    0
```

The `MailboxProcessor` adds additional level of complexity. I need a state machine which takes a state and returns a state. But it forces me to take `inbox`, which is used to receive state.

Does it has any advantages to `IObservable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not duplicates of one another. `MailboxProcessor` and `IObservable` are low-level building blocks of two different models of computation - actor model and functional reactive programming respectively.

Both deal with asynchronicity, but emphasize [different qualities](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/how-do-functional-reactive-programming-and-the-actor-model-relate-to-each-other). It's might be possible to build your solution in terms of one or the other - as you noticed in your simple example - but you will find one or the other more natural to use in a particular context.

`MailboxProcessors` are particularly useful for thread-safe, lock-free access to a resource, such as a file. You can have multiple threads manipulating the resource through an asynchronous interface, and the `MailboxProcessor` guarantees that only one of those requests is processed at a time.