# What is a good way to wrap a MailboxProcessor into and IObservable in F#?

Tags: f#, system.reactive, actor

Suppose I have a `MailboxProcessor` that takes `AsyncReplyChannel` messages an fulfills them asynchronously.

Is there an easy way to build an `IObservable` from a `MailboxProcessor` like this?

```ml
let actor = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox ->
  async {
    let mutable x = 0

    while true do
      let! ch : AsyncReplyChannel<int> = inbox.Receive ()

      ch.Reply x

      x <- x + 1
  })

let obs : IObservable<int> = Observable.ofActor actor 

actor.PostAndReply (fun ch -> ch) // Fires obs too
```

I suppose there are some decisions to be made around hot / cold observables etc.

This is touched on here: [Does MailboxProcessor just duplicate IObservable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509538/does-mailboxprocessor-just-duplicate-iobservable)

Comment: Why do that? The mailbox processor and the Observable represent two **different computing paradigms**. MailboxProcessor doesn't duplicate IObservable.  If you want to use reactive programming, you could use Reactive Extensions and have the processor post to a Subject. `IObservable` on its own doesn't offer much

Comment: A `MailboxProcessor` is a very low level construct that could be used to implement either a dataflow/CSP pipeline or agents. It's a bit too low level though, so it's far easier to use eg TPL Dataflow blocks to implement a CSP pipeline, or Akka.NET et al for agents. MailboxProcessor doesn't offer any of the features an agent framework provides, except the buffered input and worker thread.

Comment: At this point, you could even ask if you need a MailboxProcessor or if eg a Channel and `IAsyncEnumerable` could do the same job - which they could. In fact, they could provide better isolation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that I want to send ordered inputs to the process (`MailboxProcessor` works for this) but the outputs of the process can come back at uncontrolled intervals (`IObservable`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get an existing `MailboxProcessor` and obtain an `IObservable` that will get triggered whenever the mailbox processor responds to a message, then I do not think there is a way of doing this - there is no hook that would let you detect this.

The way to do this would be to define some kind of wrapper over `MailboxProcessor`. For example you could define `NotifyingMailboxProcessor<'Msg, 'Evt>` that triggers an event of type `'Evt` each time a message of type `'Msg` is processed. You could start with something like this:

```
type NotifyingMailboxProcessor<'Msg, 'Evt>(mbox:MailboxProcessor<'T>) = 
  let evt = Event<'E>()
  member x.OnPostAndReply = evt.Publish
  member x.PostAndReply<'R>(f:AsyncReplyChannel<'R> -> 'T, g:'T -> 'R -> 'E) = 
    let mutable msg = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    let res = mbox.PostAndReply(fun ch -> msg <- f(ch); msg)
    evt.Trigger(g msg res)
    res

type NotifyingMailboxProcessor =
  static member Start<'Msg, 'Evt>(f) = 
    NotifyingMailboxProcessor<'Msg, 'Evt>(MailboxProcessor.Start(f))
```

This emulates the standard interface, so you can create one using `NotifyingMailboxProcessor.Start`. A subtle issue is that to wrap `PostAndReply`, you need to give it another function that constructs the event `'Evt` from a pair consisting of the message sent to the mailbox and the reply (these can have different types, so you have to wrap the result into a type `'Evt`, much like you have to wrap multiple message types into a single discriminated union, typically).

An example inspired by your motivating one would then be:

```
let actor = NotifyingMailboxProcessor.Start<AsyncReplyChannel<int>, int>(fun inbox ->
  async {
    let mutable x = 0
    while true do
      let! (ch : AsyncReplyChannel<int>) = inbox.Receive ()
      ch.Reply x
      x <- x + 1
  })

actor.OnPostAndReply.Add(printfn "Message: %A")
actor.PostAndReply((fun ch -> ch), (fun msg ans -> ans))
```